# What status code should we return if the POST succeeds but does not result in creating anything new?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

We have an endpoint which when you post create a new version of resource and returns a 201 and the location of the newly created resource. It determines the new version number based on a comparison of the current version and the version being posted (using a semver like ruleset).

If the version you post is identical to the existing version then no version number is updated. What should we return in this case?

- We could just return a 201 even though we have not technically created anything.
- I don't want to return a 409 as its not really a conflict, like when you post something with the same id. If you posted the same thing when the existing version was slightly different then you would happily get a 201.
- We could just return a 200, but then that would seem weird, and increases the response codes that the users have to deal with

Does the idempotency of the 201 response matter?

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Care to tell us which request method is being used here? Just `POST`? Possibly `PUT`? I think 409 is not that far off here.

Comment: it's just `POST`, never `PUT`

Comment: Semantically, is it an update? If so, `204` (no content in the response body) and `200` can be returned if the operation succeeds. If the operation fails, `400` or even `422` are candidates.

Comment: sematically I suppose it is an update, ie the post updates the representation to match the data posted and returns the version number. If the new representation is the same as the existing representation then the version number does not need to be changed

Comment: Depending on what will be returned in the response, I would go for `204` or `200`.

Comment: Personally, I return `HTTP 420` because _nothing gets done_. This may be too subtle - and does conflict with Twitter's use of HTTP 420.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about 303 - See Other? Seems to fit. I draw your attention to this sentence
from the spec at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

> This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource.

That sounds like what you want to do to me. Here's the rest of it.

10.3.4 303 See Other

The response to the request can be found under a different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second (redirected) request might be cacheable.

The different URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).

```
  Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303
  status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the
  302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react
  to a 302 response as described here for 303
```

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit puzzled by the other answers as some get it *almost* right. So, let's clear up things a bit. If all requests are indeed performed with the `POST` method, in the context of ReSTfulness, they are supposed to modify state on the target server. Otherwise, the meaning of `POST` is a bit relaxed as you can see in [RFC 7231, sec. 4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3).

Since the intent of the requests is to create a new version of a resource, they have *failed* if a version with the given presentation already exists. This would disqualify any 2xx-class response codes. From [section 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3):

> The 2xx (Successful) class of status code indicates that the client's request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.

If you absolutely wanted to, you could go for [202/Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3), which "is intentionally noncommittal." This is a bit of a stretch, though, as this status code is intended for queued processing. I would advise against it.

The [204/No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) code suggested by others is a bit of a poor choice. It were absolutely correct if you `POST`ed to the resource you were updating, though.

As the result is neither informational (1xx) nor a fault by the server (5xx). Let us have a look at the 3xx class first. From [section 6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4):

> The 3xx (Redirection) class of status code indicates that further action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.

One of the most prominent one here would be [304/Not Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1). While sounding like a perfect fit, this code is unfortunately not applicable here. It can only be returned in response to conditional `GET` or `HEAD` requests.

[302/Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3) may sound like the next best fit. However, this code is intended for temporary redirects, which is in all likelyhood not what you want.

As has been suggested here, [303/See Other](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) is indeed a good choice:

> The 303 (See Other) status code indicates that the server is redirecting the user agent to a different resource [...] which is intended to provide an indirect response to the original request.
> [...]
> This status code is applicable to any HTTP method.  It is primarily used to allow the output of a POST action to redirect the user agent to a selected resource

All other 3xx codes are dealing with various forms of redirects that hardly relate to the situation here.

A final look, 4xx-class of status codes. From [RFC 7231, sec. 6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5):

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. These status codes are applicable to any request method.

Very few of these are actually deeling with the request body. Two of those who do would stand out here: One is [400/Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1), which is by design overly broad. It is - if you will - a catch-all solution. However, this would imply that the request body is malformed (as in syntactically incorrect) in some way, which is probably not the case.

More interesting is [409/Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8). From the RFC (emphasis mine):

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not be completed **due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource**.

The wording of the definition places this code close to the `PUT` method, but is not exclusive. To reiterate the definition of the 4xx codes:

> These status codes are applicable to any request method.

[422/Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) is a contender, but it implies a semantic error, which really isn't the case here.

Ultimately (drumroll) the final piece of the puzzle could be found in [section 4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3):

> If the result of processing a POST would be equivalent to a representation of an existing resource, an origin server MAY redirect the user agent to that resource by sending a 303 (See Other) response with the existing resource's identifier in the Location field.

Note the "MAY." So you can really choose between 303 and 409. I feel 409 were the better fit, as clearly an earlier request introduced a state that is incompatible with the current one. OTOH, 303 may be the politer way to go and is closer to the standard. Either way, as a consumer of your API, I would really like to know if my requests failed. And be it by not having any effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing has been created by the operation, `201` is not suitable for that:

> [**6.3.2. 201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created. [...]

See below some options you could consider if the operation succeeds:

> [**6.3.1. 200 OK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)
>
> The `200` (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded. The payload sent in a `200` response depends on the request method. For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> [...]
>
> - `POST`: a representation of the status of, or results obtained from, the action;
>
> [...]
>
> Aside from responses to `CONNECT`, a `200` response always has a payload, though an origin server MAY generate a payload body of zero length. If no payload is desired, an origin server ought to send `204` (No Content) instead. [...]

> [**6.3.5. 204 No Content**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)
>
> The `204` (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body. [...]

If the operation fails:

> [**6.5.1. 400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

> [**11.2. 422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)  status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Answer (score 1):

A `201 Created` should be used whenever you creating a new resource without doubt.

As defined in [HTTP Method Definitions RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), either`200 Ok` or `204 No Content`is an appropriate response if the operation does not create a new resource depending on the response body content.

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource
>   that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204
>   (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether
>   or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.
>
> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).

Now, coming back to your original question about what to use when the operation is successful and there is nothing to return, you should use `204 No Content`. This status code is specifically meant for scenarios where the requested operation is successfully completed but there is no additional relevant information that the server can provide.

> The `204` (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that for this case the idempotency is an issue, because the state of the system is not the same as it was in the inicial request, because the entity now exists, so you can respond with a different code.

200 should be fine, but it is a little weird as you said.

I have never use this, but I read that for some case you should redirect with a 302, to make a get for other resource, in this case I think this apply, return a 302 and make a get pointing for the old semver, assuming that you have a get endpoint for this entity.

Answer (score 0):

If the POST'd resource has the same version number, but different data, then a `409` would be fitting.  But if the data is the same as what's already stored, then a `409` might not be required. Through process of elimination I would say `200 OK` would be fine.

> We could just return a 200, but then that would seem weird, and increases the response codes that the users have to deal with

If this is a costly concern, consider eliminating the `201`, not the `200`.  The fact of the matter is that for any decently complex service there may be at some point a situation where a `20X` (where X is not 0) is applicable.  So does that mean we code with each of the `20X` responses in mind and spend time checking if our services has situations where `20X` is preferred over `200`?  I suspect not.  So unless there is a specific reason to respond with a `20X`, for example to deal with a specific use case, then just use `200` and reduce the amount of coding and documenting required.  I suspect for most scenarios, the calling client does not care.

Comment: The posted thing doesn't contain a version number, the version number is calculated based on the contents. Hence wanting it returned, and no conflict

Comment: So then no 409.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the correct answer probably depends on whatever client is consuming your API. If you are building the client too, you could do whatever you prefer... (Just don't get too crazy.)

---

**Assuming you are writing the API and client**:

My opinion/suggestion is...

- If there **IS** a new version number: The [`201`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) HTTP status code would fit will.
- If there is **NOT** a new version number: The [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) or [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) HTTP status code would fit well.
- If there is no benefit to the client knowing the version number has changed or is the same: Send the [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) HTTP status code.

**If you don't control the client consuming your API:** Obviously defer to what they expect.

---

You may also wish review all of the [HTTP Status Codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) in the HTTP RFC spec. The above status codes also link directly to the relevant section.

Answer (score 0):

`201` : when new version is created

`202` : when existing version is updated

`204` : when request is accepted but no processing is done

**by def, 204 = No Content**

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

So its slight tangential to your needs but I think its the best fit.

Comment: "`202` : when existing version is updated" Citation needed. My understanding of that status code is entirely different.

Comment: its suggestive, not derived from protocol  def