# Spring boot : RestTemplate POST call does not return created status code

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, resttemplate

I'm new to spring boot rest template. I'm trying write unit test case for rest template post call.
I've created a user controller to send the dummy data.
Is the Usercontroller written for POST call is correct for unit test? If not what is the correct way to write it? Is the response I'm returning from usercontroller correct? Should I return status code as 200 or 201?
Can someone help me?

Below is the usercontroller

```
@PostMapping("/users")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.add("Hi");

        User createUser = new User();
        createUser.setId(1);
        createUser.setName("John");
        createUser.setAge(22);
        createUser.setMessages(messages);
        return user;
    }
```

Below id the unit test case for post call:

```
@Test
    public void testSuccessPostUser() throws Exception{
        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/users";
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.add("Hi");

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setName("John");
        user.setAge(22);
        user.setMessages(messages);

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<User> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(user, httpHeaders);

        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        ResponseEntity<User>  actual = httpHandler.sendPost(baseUrl, httpHeaders, user, User.class);

        //verify request succeed
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, actual.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(201, actual.getStatusCodeValue());
        assertTrue(responseBody.contains(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST returns 200 by default.

If you want to make it return 201 add this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@PostMapping("/users")
public User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return custom status codes, you should return `RepsponseEntity`:

```
@PostMapping("/users")
public ResposneEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user){
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

If you want to know correct https statuses for a POST method I suggest to read this: [What status code should we return if the POST succeeds but does not result in creating anything new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327963/what-status-code-should-we-return-if-the-post-succeeds-but-does-not-result-in-cr)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for testing HTTP controller You can use `MockMvc`.

Examples test:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       .content("{ "id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 22 }") 
       .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
       .andExpect(status().isCreated())
       .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value($id)) 
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.value").value("some-value"));
```

More details in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server)

To return 201 code, You need to add `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)` in Your controller.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, Don't we use mockMvc for integration testing?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I assume Your case is integration test :)

Comment: I'm writing unit test. What is the correct way to write it?

Comment: You call an endpoint `http://localhost:8080/users`, if it's not stubbed your type of test is integration. `MockMvc` provides an elegant and easy to use API to call web endpoints and inspect and assert their response at the same time. You must add `@ContextConfiguration` and `@WebAppConfiguration` to test for preparing spring context for testing.

Comment: I'm using junit5 to write unit test cases. I'm using ```@SpringBootTest``` annotation. Do I still need ```@contextConfiguration``` and ```@WebAppConfiguration```? Also, when you say preparing spring context for testing what does it exactly mean?

Comment: @SpringBootTest runs full-context spring. It's just enough for You. Now, just add `@Autowire MockMvc mockMvc` and use it in test :) @WebAppConfiguration, this runs only web layer.

Comment: Sure, will add mockMvc and use it in the test. Thank you for your time and all the help.